# Countable or uncountable?

Tags: calculus

> Countable or uncountable?
>   (a) $x\in\Bbb Q:|x|>4$
>   (b) $x^2 :x\in\Bbb Q$

I understand that $\Bbb Q$ itself is countable but what I am confused about is that $x\in\Bbb Q$. Is this saying $x$ is an element of $\Bbb Q$? Is $x$ not just a single element of $\Bbb Q$ such as 30/7 for example how can it have a cardinality? Can an element of a set have its own cardinality? I don't see how you can tell if it's greater than 4. I'm aware that my reasoning is greatly flawed here its just I can't find any information anywhere to guide me in the direction to solve this question.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to tell us what you think the answer is, and why, What do you know about the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes. It is true that both sets are either countable or uncountable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cardinality is defined for a set, and not for each element. Both (a) and (b) are set defined in set builder form and subsets of a countable set $\Bbb(Q)$, and hence countable.
Check [Subset of a countable set is itself countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551630/subset-of-a-countable-set-is-itself-countable)